# How to construct addToFront method

Tags: arraylist, constructor

I have a IUArrayList class which implements IndexedUnsortedList interface and I have some constructors written but I need help writing the addToFront method. I have the addToRear method written and some other constructors done but I'm not sure about how to do addToFront. If you need to see more code let me know but this arraylist also uses an iterator which I keep track of with the modCount variable.

```
public class IUArrayList<T> implements IndexedUnsortedList<T> {
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
private static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;

private T[] array;
private int rear;
private int modCount;

/** Creates an empty list with default initial capacity */
public IUArrayList() {
    this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
}

/** 
 * Creates an empty list with the given initial capacity
 * @param initialCapacity
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public IUArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    array = (T[])(new Object[initialCapacity]);
    rear = 0;
    modCount = 0;
}

/** Double the capacity of array */
private void expandCapacity() {
    array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length*2);
}

@Override
public void addToFront(T element) {
    // TODO 
    
}

@Override
public void addToRear(T element) {
    expandCapacity();
    array[rear] = element;
    rear++;
    modCount++; 
}
```

Below is the Interface that it implements.

```
public interface IndexedUnsortedList<T> extends Iterable<T>
{
/**  
 * Adds the specified element to the front of this list. 
 *
 * @param element the element to be added to the front of this list    
 */
public void addToFront(T element);  

/**  
 * Adds the specified element to the rear of this list. 
 *
 * @param element the element to be added to the rear of this list    
 */
public void addToRear(T element);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `LinkedList` instead of Array. You would be able to utilize `addFirst` and `addLast` methods of `LinkedList` to achieve what you want to achieve.